# Use standard input in a shellscript

Tags: shell, variables, scripting, stdin

We have to make a script that interacts with the standard input, wich is a file and we put a keystring on it, but the difficulty of this exercise is that the file can't be found in some cases, so we have to save the filename to a variable

key.sh (keystring) < (filename)

how can i save the filename into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

In `key.sh`, you want to have a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# assign the input string to the variable filename
filename="$1"
```

Then you would actually call the script with `key.sh filename`